# How to check if a "webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate" page has been "navigated"

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working with a Chrome Extension developed in jQuery and I want to trigger a script each time some page is opened.

This script is listed in `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    ...
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            ...,
            "js": [
                "src/this_script.js",
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It works OK when:

- Clicking an external link with the proper URL of such page
- Refreshing the page
- Most of the times I click to its link from other pages on this site

However, sometimes this link appears at the site in a way that clicking to it does change the URL and the content but it **does not** trigger `this_script.js`.

I just need to know how to identify when an URL changes (e.g.: `changeInfo.status === 'complete'`) doesn't triggers a `webNavigation` event.

With this I'd easly refresh the page with a simple *`location.href`*.

Regards,
Juan Vicente

Comment: Sounds like "soft navigation" via history.pushState. You can use MutationObserver inside this_script.js to detect changes in the page or chrome.tabs.onUpdated in the background script.

Comment: OK, I'll check this idea ASAP.
Thanks :)